# How to execute html code in curly braces with angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I use AngularJS with a database. I get data with html code. But the html code is displayed instead of executed.

This is the html code :

```
<a href="https://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=h7JbohyS4d4&offerid=571616.12819347524&type=2&murl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.marimekko.com%2Fus_en%2Fsitriini-husina-dress-046222-910%3Ffee%3D1%26fep%3D48683">
  <IMG border=0 width=100% src="https://www.marimekko.com/media/catalog/product/0/4/046222-910_10_1528138086.jpg" >
</a>
<IMG border=0 width=1 height=1 src="https://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=h7JbohyS4d4&bids=571616.12819347524&type=2&subid=0" >
```

This code should display an image with a link instead of code only

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names">
  <div>{{ x.Detail }}</div>  
  <div>{{ x.Company }}</div>
  <div>{{ x.Price }}</div>
  <div>{{ x.Link }}</div>
</div>
```

Here do I get the data from the database?

Comment: What do you mean HTML is not executed? HTML is not executable it's presentational language. The very M in HTML means markup.

Comment: When I say execute, it means that the html tags are displayed instead of an image with a link.